# Linking problem due to changing the cpp directory

Tags: c++, boost, extern

I am a java programmer; so I'm facing a lot of problems when it comes to c++ due to the linking stuff and so on. The problem basically is that I want to re-factor a single file (Transformation.cpp) into (TrasnformationBackend.cpp), (TrasnformationFrontend.cpp) and a header file. As you may see, I needed to declare a global struct through the all the files, and I did that using the "extern" in the header file and it works fine. However, unresolved external error appears when I try to move the frontend cpp file into a different directory.

By the way, I'm using BOOST.

Comment: What error? What compiler/IDE?

Comment: unresolved external, the struct is already defined, I'm using boost building tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `extern` declaration in a header only tells the compiler that that variable will be defined in a compilation unit. It does not actually create that variable / allocate storage for it.

If you have in your `.h`:

```
extern int globalvar;
```

You need in one, and only one, of your `.cpp` files:

```
int globalvar;
```

Otherwise compilation will go ok, but link will fail because that external cannot be resolved.

Comment: This is what I did, and it compiled and ran successfully .. the problem appeared when I moved the cpp file.

Comment: Your IDE is unlikely to detect magically where your .cpp file went, and therefore it's likely that all its contents are now missing from your program.

Comment: Thanks, this could be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

"...error appears when I try to move the frontend cpp file into a different directory."

OK if you look in your compiler/IDE settings there'll be a setting for which directory(ies) it will search through to find .cpp file(s); you need to add the new directory here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem isn't that the compiler can't locate the cpp file in the new directory .. I think it has something to do with the linking.

Comment: Because it actually builds and outputs an unresolved external error